# char [1024] vs char *

Tags: c, char

I am trying to study C, and I am running in to troubles using char* and char arrays. I am using a generic hash-set container from a library (which I don't want to describe in details). This library includes the function

```
void *HashSetLookup(hashset *h, const void *elemAddr);
```

which I have to use to search in the hash set to see if the element already exists there (the hash and compare functions are part of the hashset struct). In this case I use the hashset to store pointers to C-strings, or more specifically (char * *) .  My problem is that the following code gives a segmentation fault:

```
    char word[1024];
    /* Some code that writes to the word buffer */
    HashSetLookup(stopList, &word);
```

while this code works fine (and as expected):

```
    char word[1024];
    /* The same code as before that writes to the word buffer */
    char* tmp = strdup(word);
    HashSetLookup(stopList, &tmp);
    free(tmp);
```

I thought char word[] and char* were basically the same thing. The only difference being that char word[1024] is in the stack with a fixed length of 1024, but tmp in the heap occupying only as much space as necessary (strlen(word)+1).

Therefore I don't understand why I have to make a copy of the string in the heap to be able to call this function. Why does this happen? Is there some more fundamental difference between char* tmp = strdup("something") and char word[1024] = "something"?

Comment: Show the code that writes to word in the first example.

Comment: I don't see the variable `tmp` being declared/used before the function call in the first sample.

Comment: MAK, sorry that was an error. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Jergason, I was thinking about doing that, but that code is basically a list of five function calls, which all are rather complicated. I don't think that would help at all. I have however made sure that i actually writes to word, so that is not the problem. In fact word will contain the word "BBC" (closed by \0 of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mention you need a `char **` and there lies the problem: for an array, `word` and `&word` mean the same thing - the actual location of the array contents. The reason it works when you use a pointer is because the "pointer" is *stored* at a different location, while it *points* to the same array. You don't need an `strdup`, you simply need to create a pointer:

```
char* tmp = word;
HashSetLookup(stopList, &tmp);
```

Comment: Glad it works. It's one of those subtle differences between an array and a pointer.

Comment: -1 because the answer is plain wrong.
It *does* make a fundamental difference if you pass tmp or &tmp. Try it yourself and you will see that something else comes along. You could use &tmp[0] though.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. `tmp` and `&tmp` are obviously different because `tmp` is a pointer. But `word` and `&word` are the same because `word` is an array. I've tried it several times and did so even before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without the documentation of HashSetLookup.

But it expects a const void * as its second parameter, so you should pass tmp, and not &tmp, because tmp is already a pointer.

I don't see need for char ** here at all.

Also, you might probably be interested in what HashSetLookup() returns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I actually need to store char** since the HashSet will copy whatever the void pointer points to to a fixed size chunk of memory. This would not work well for strings since they are of various sizes. Therefore all the HashSet functions will need to take in char** since I only want to store pointers to strings stored in the heap. 

And you are right, I am interested in whatever the HashSetLookup() returns. But since it crashed at this point I didn't bother including it in the code.

Comment: Your signatures and the values you pass do not represent that. If you think it is working now, it is most probably due to just another bug.

Answer (score 0):

You must have missed something in the first example because "word" is not being used at all.

Anyhow, in most of the environments, when you write 'char *s = "Hello World"', it gets created on the code segment and cannot be modified. Code segment means that it is part of the executable code which must not be modified but only read. When you try to write it, you get a seg fault.

However 'char[]' gets created on data segment so it can be modified without any problem.

Comment: He says in the comment for the first example that there is some code left out that writes to word.

Comment: you are right. In the first code it should have been HashSetLookup(stopList, &word), not HashSetLookup(stopList, &tmp);

I have fixed that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps:

http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Why_arrays_arent_pointers

http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `char**` I think the problem is with the function trying to *write* to the location pointed by the second argument, i.e. when you write:

```
HashSetLookup( stopList, &word );
```

it goes and tries assigning an address to `word` (and that's why it needs the *address* of it.), which overwrites the buffer with a pointer.

This is demonstrated by the following silly snippet (keep in mind that address of array is still the address of its first element):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func( void* boo )
{
        char** ptr = ( char** )boo;
        printf( "func: got %p\n", boo );
        *ptr = "bad func";
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
        char buf[128], *p;
        func( &buf ); /* buf got overwritten */
        printf( "array: %s\n", buf );
        p = malloc( 128 );
        func( &p ); /* p got new value */
        printf( "malloc: %s\n", p );
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought something similar at first. But if you look at the prototype for HashSetLookup you see that the second argument is a pointer to a const. And secondy, this is only a lookup function and it shouldn't write anything at all.